# Skip invalid record and avoid execution break for invalid record

Tags: performance, ruby, ruby-on-rails

Here is the pseudo code used inside a Rails controller:

```
defined_hash_10000_records.each do |data|
    account = Account.where(account_identifier: params[:account_id]).first
    program = Program.where(program_identifier: data[:id]).first
    unless participant_account.present? || utility_program.present?
      # this is just a logger method defined in the second file.
      failure_msg('participant account is #{account.inspect} & utility program is #{program.inspect}')
      next
    end
    sub = Subscription.where(account_id: account.id, program_id: program.id)
end
```

It is working fine and I would like to know if it can be further improved.

Focus to improve the following line (conditions will help to bypass in case record not found instead of break the execution):

```
unless participant_account.present? || utility_program.present?
      # this is just a logger method defined in the second file.
      failure_msg('participant account is #{account.inspect} & utility program is #{program.inspect}')
      next
    end
```

Comment: What do you want to improve? speed? memory? readability?

Comment: readability and memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Simplify logic to eliminate next

To improve readability by eliminating `next`, rearrange your record validity test, so lines 4 to 9 become

```
if participant_account.present? || utility_program.present?
  sub = Subscription.where(account_id: account.id, program_id: program.id)
else
  # this is just a logger method defined in the second file.
  failure_msg('participant account is #{account.inspect} & utility program is #{program.inspect}')
end
```

I am not sure this is what you mean. Ask yourself if you really need only one of `participant_account` or `utility_program` for the subscription query to succeed.

#### Don't do things many times that could be done once

To save some time, put line two before the iteration, because value of `account` does not depend on `data`. This also helps readability and debugging, as when programmers read the body of an iteration, they  expect only to see lines that need to be evaluated many times.

#### Only make queries if you need the result

To save a little more time and memory, only calculate the value of `program` *if* you know you are going to use it. So put it inside the conditional:

```
if participant_account.present? && utility_program.present?
  program = Program.where(program_identifier: data[:id]).first
  sub = Subscription.where(account_id: account.id, program_id: program.id)
else # ...
```

#### Extract methods

After these changes the conditional is starting to get a bit complicated, so extract some methods, for example:

```
if participant_account.present? && utility_program.present?
  sub = subscription(account, first_program(data))
else # ...

def subscription(account, program)
  Subscription.where(account_id: account.id, program_id: program.id)
end

def first_program(data)
  Program.where(program_identifier: data[:id]).first
end
```

#### Put query logic in models

I don't know if Program is an ActiveRecord model. If it is, then `#first_program` could be a class method in that model

#### Don't use #first unless you guarantee the order

For example, if you have ActiveRecord timestamps, you could use

```
Program.where(program_identifier: data[:id]).order(:created_at).first
```

#### Are validation and failure handling cross-cutting concerns?

You might also want to consider patterns that factor out your validation and failure handling code, but whether and how to use them depends on the larger structure of your program. For example, you could yield to your validations and `sub = ...` line as lambdas from a `validate_with_logging` method.